# how to turn on mic in android and record sound in temporary file

Tags: android

I want to turn on the MIC when app is run and store this sound temporary and after that send me the sound level in dp.is it possible to create this app.plese help me

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Microphone volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928202/get-microphone-volume)

Comment: See also [Getting decibel from an android microphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271989/getting-decibel-from-an-android-microphone)

Answer (score 1):

Please visit the following [Recording tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

This part in particular:

```
String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
    throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
}

// make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
  throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
}

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Furthermore it is not strictly necessery to record a file to run an *sound level* check, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777060/android-sample-microphone-without-recording-to-get-live-amplitude-level)

Comment: I am not getting where i have to start.plz give me solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with creating android applications?

Comment: yaa,i have created so many application..

Comment: and I got the error in this app,that same error i found in  this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=868448&goto=nextoldest,and no solutions is there now plz help me